# How can I find out my WiFi adapter's MAC address on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, mac-address

What command can I enter in a terminal to find out the MAC address of my WiFi adapter?

Answer (score 27):

The command

```
ip addr
```

will tell. `ifconfig` is a tool obsolete since 2001.

Comment: In fact quite before that. I remember that we switched our self-made carrier-grade Linux (for ISPs) completely over to iproute2 back in summer of 1999; and before that we had already used it for a couple of months. In 1999, ifconfig was already quite faulty with regard to VPN device setups (secondary IP addresses with aliases), like CIPE for example and exhibited massive race conditions if you had to reconfigure a box with hundreds of running VPN tunnels. Our boxes had up to 16 NICs (quad boards) and route had a problem sometimes displaying our hundreds of routing table entries.

Comment: How will it tell? The output I get from that command means nothing to me.

Answer (score 9):

Combining the answer from @user562374 with a little scripting:

```
ip addr show $(awk 'NR==3{print $1}' /proc/net/wireless | tr -d :) | awk '/ether/{print $2}'
```

The wireless interface is shown in `/proc/net/wireless` and that is used to extract the MAC address from the `ip addr` output.

Answer (score 6):

For details about your wifi interface, use

```bsh
iw dev
```

Or, if you just want the MAC address

```bsh
iw dev | grep addr | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: This answer is current and correct as of 2021. The original question and most of the other answers are over a decade old!

Answer (score 4):

You will want to look at `iwconfig` and `ifconfig` for information about your ethernet controllers.  `iwconfig` is geared towards wireless.

Answer (score 3):

From the [arch wiki docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing):

To find the MAC address that corresponds with a particular interface (ie wlan0), you can enter this command:

```
ip link show <interface-name>
```

The MAC address is the one that has "link/ether" followed by a 6-byte number. It will probably look something like this:

```
link/ether e8:b1:fc:9c:a6:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Where the MAC address is `e8:b1:fc:9c:a6:8a`

*If you don't know your interface name, just enter `ip link` to list the MAC addresses and interface names of all your interfaces. *

Answer (score 2):

```
/sbin/ifconfig | grep HWaddr
```

You can add the interface name of your WiFi card (e.g. `wlan0`) after ifconfig, but it's not necessary.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10 systems, the wifi interface is `eth1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ip addr show $(iw dev | awk '/Interface/{print $2}') | awk '/ether/{print $2}'
```

works on Debian and Ubuntu

Comment: It's always best to explain your answer for future visitors.  Please take some time to do it.

Comment: Example output?